# Delete a file from a SVN repo managed by git svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I have an SVN repo managed by git-svn . I can't delete a file and send my commits to SVN server. Here is what I am doing:

git rm myfile.txt
git commit -m "removed not necessary file"
git svn dcommit 
throws:
Can't open myfile.txt No such file or directory

I had to hard reset HEAD in order to be able to pull from SVN. Anyone else had this problem ? How did you fixed it ?

Comment: Ok, stoooopid me, the file that I deleted was used by 'svn.authorsfile' . I cleared the property and everything is fine.

Comment: Add this as an answer, please, so the question will not stay unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, stoooopid me, the file that I deleted was used by 'svn.authorsfile' . 
I cleared the property and everything is fine.